# Are users auto redirected to success url in paypal?

Tags: paypal

There is a success url option when you create the buy now button. But also there is this option on Website Payment Preferences. What I wonder is, are users auto redirected to success url or return url ?

[image]

Comment: What does Paypal say about the success URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the buttons, the success url that you set in the button code will override the return URL that you set in the account.  Also keep in mind that buyers only making a payment with a PayPal account will be automatically returned to your site.  Buyers that make the payment using a credit card, will have to click a link/button once they have made the payment on the PayPal page to return to your site.  This is done so that they can either print a copy of the receipt from that page, write the info down or etc before they are returned to your site.  Unlike buyers that use PayPal accounts to make the payment, these buyers that use credit cards can not always get back to these details.  Some one that pays with their PayPal account can simply log into their account and view these details at any time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My last question is, are users auto redirect to success url, or they have to click "return to merchant's site" to redirect ?

Comment: If the merchant is paying with a PayPal account, they will be auto redirected.  If they are paying with a credit care (No PayPal account), they will have to click a link to return to your site.